# How to correct Default settings which show errors when settings.json in .config/Code/User doesn't have those settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem with how something basic is handled in one of my VSCode workspaces. In trying to fix this problem I ran into the problem stated in the title:

~/.config/Code/User/settings.json does not have

```
"C_Cpp.default.dotConfig": null
```

(It's not even mentioned there) but it shows in the apparently virtual defaultSettings.json  when you open it in the editor.

There are apparently 24 problems with settings values in "defaultSettings.json". How can I correct those settings?

Bonus question: Why isn't VSCode maintaining these settings correctly, given that "defaultSettings.json" is read-only?